# Installing ubuntu 14.4.3 server on KVM without internet

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I was trying to install ubuntu server 14.04.3 as a guest on KVM as referred in this [link](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/testcases/1441/revisions/1226/info)

I made sure that the guest server doesn't have network. Following command used for installation:

```
sudo virt-install -r 1024  --nonetworks -n test1 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/st1.img,size=30 --location /home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso --extra-args "console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial"
```

Although the ubuntu installer didn't recognise any network interface it still asked for mirror source and I couldn't continue to install the system.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

Ubuntu installation process is different when installing using direct connection (Monitor,Keyboard, Mouse)/VNC and when installing via serial port (Console).
It looks like that there is a bug when installing via serial port that cause the installation to not permit to continue to rest of the installation when mirror site isn't available. The only way to install ubuntu server as a guest without internet is using VNC. Using VNC there is no need to remove network interface, it just automatically detect that the internet isn't available and skip the requirement to have mirror site available. I have tested is on ubuntu servers 14,15 and 16.

Comment: Are you using some the normal ISO or the minimal one?

Comment: normal  iso server amd_64

Comment: Hmm... wouldn't it work for you if you initially enable the network and disable it right after finishing the installation?

Comment: Can't finish the installation since the installation is looking for a mirror server and I can't continue without it.

Comment: What is the exact step where you get stuck? I am doing it now with the 16.04 daily, and it looks as though it is going to finish fine (currently doing step 24).

Comment: I can't continue since I can't skip "Choose a mirror of the Ubuntu archive" step. It is not possible to continue without connection to the Ubuntu archive server.

Comment: did you try using -c instead --location? as far as I could determine that is the root issue.

Comment: Not sure if -c will solve the issue, in any case when using -c its not possible to use --extra-args "console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial" which provides the ability to use console.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your virt-install command is incorrect for a no-network installation.

the --location argument requires a network connection for your guest.

The -c or --cdrom= argument needs to be used to specify the iso file name.

I did the no-network test case, but using the a recent 16.04 64 bit server edition daily iso file. It worked fine. This was my command line:

```
sudo virt-install -n serv64_dev -r 8192 \
--disk path=/media/newhd/serv64_dev.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
-c xenial-server-amd64-20151214.iso \
--nonetworks \
--video=vmvga --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole -v --vcpus=4
```

Make sure that you have downloaded the correct iso file, and verify the md5sum. Examples:

```
$ ls -l xenial-server-amd64-20151215.iso
-rw-rwxr-- 1 doug doug 752877568 Dec 15 07:45 xenial-server-amd64-20151215.iso
$ md5sum xenial-server-amd64-20151215.iso
e10efef1980fb712e7dfd8d79d6542c2  xenial-server-amd64-20151215.iso
```

Now, I compare with the list [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/20151215/MD5SUMS), copied below:

```
e10efef1980fb712e7dfd8d79d6542c2 *xenial-server-amd64.iso
994dd089239adca6421d5deeed528a0b *xenial-server-amd64.squashfs
e28ecd7acc603a903e1877ad6f11bcbd *xenial-server-i386.iso
f6a6a89b2acbe8af285761ddc8545fa0 *xenial-server-i386.squashfs
04bf8218848474c1b305f0bf010990e3 *xenial-server-powerpc.iso
3da7885f81135632443c27ca7b83ef6c *xenial-server-powerpc.squashfs
21f874ed087e92a45c40afebef71a12f *xenial-server-ppc64el.iso
d7435980bc32b3e3962d6a8400e3dea3 *xenial-server-ppc64el.squashfs
86c6c2dadf39cc317f2e1a828ccbb401 *xenial-server-s390x.iso
65e71b1f0eb45f6fc0739c2d0659f99b *xenial-server-s390x.squashfs
```

Observe that the my checksum agrees with what is listed on the web site.

Comment: Download the same iso and got the same error. Since it's installation via console instead of "-c" used "--location" and --extra-args "console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial". This is the only major difference i can see between the command lines. without this I can't get console to do the installation.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is your host running? I am running 14.04.3 server edition 64 bit on my host. What step of the test case are you on?

Comment: The host is 14.04.3 server 64 bit edition. Tried to install 14.x,15.x and 16.x server 64bit as guest, for each of the installations I reach the same step. I reach the ubuntu archive selection step and can't continue after it since internet isn't available.

Comment: I am confused. There is no "ubuntu archive selection" step. At what step of the test procedure of your link do you get these directions? Give a step number reference. Your iso file is 752877568 bytes, correct?

Comment: There is  "ubuntu archive selection" step, When selecting one of the archive sites (i.e. us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) I get archive error since the server isn't connected to the internet and I can't go forward after this step. correct, the size of the xenial server version is 725614592 bytes.

Comment: Go to your test case link and post back the step number when you are asked to select a mirror site. For example say something like "It asks me to select a mirror site between steps 11 and 12" or "It asks me to select a mirror site before step 2, right after boot". I think you have the wrong iso, and have edited my answer to add a way to check.

Comment: It asks me to select a mirror between steps 12 and 13. I can't skip it so I don't reach 13.

Comment: iso issues aside, the only difference I can think of between us is possible country and / or language differences. You could try "Canada" and "English" or tell me what you enter and I'll try them.

Comment: I think that I found the problem, When installing from server using console and not VNC, the installation fails due to request for mirror site. When installing using VNC/GUI, the ubuntu server installation is different and it doesn't ask for mirror site when network fails.